# Arduino Ethernet web server problems

Tags: c, arduino, ethernet

I got some problems with my Arduino code i made a Arduino Ethernet SD web server its task is to get a comand and light a Power switch and show if the switch is on or off Everything works perfect. But the problem is that i can connect to arduino web server a couple of times then something happens and i cant connect to it then i have to restart it to be able to connect to it again. Could any one pls help me?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <RemoteTransmitter.h>
// size of buffer used to capture HTTP requests
#define REQ_BUF_SZ   60

// MAC address from Ethernet shield sticker under board
byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0E, 0x95, 0x2F };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 200); // IP address, may need to change depending on network
EthernetServer server(80);  // create a server at port 80
File webFile;               // the web page file on the SD card
char HTTP_req[REQ_BUF_SZ] = {0}; // buffered HTTP request stored as null terminated string
char req_index = 0;              // index into HTTP_req buffer
boolean LED_state[3] = {0}; // stores the states of the LEDs
ActionTransmitter actionTransmitter(9);

void setup()
{
  // Everything resets to Off if arduino is reseted
  actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'A',false);
  actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'B',false);
  actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'C',false);

    // disable Ethernet chip
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);

    Serial.begin(9600);       // for debugging

    // initialize SD card
    Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
    if (!SD.begin(4)) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
        return;    // init failed
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - SD card initialized.");
    // check for index.htm file
    if (!SD.exists("index.htm")) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - Can't find index.htm file!");
        return;  // can't find index file
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - Found index.htm file.");


    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);  // initialize Ethernet device
    server.begin();           // start to listen for clients
}

void loop()
{
    EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client

    if (client) {  // got client?
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
                char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
                // limit the size of the stored received HTTP request
                // buffer first part of HTTP request in HTTP_req array (string)
                // leave last element in array as 0 to null terminate string (REQ_BUF_SZ - 1)
                if (req_index < (REQ_BUF_SZ - 1)) {
                    HTTP_req[req_index] = c;          // save HTTP request character
                    req_index++;
                }
                // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
                // respond to client only after last line received
                if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
                    // send a standard http response header
                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    // remainder of header follows below, depending on if
                    // web page or XML page is requested
                    // Ajax request - send XML file
                    if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "ajax_inputs")) {
                        // send rest of HTTP header
                        client.println("Content-Type: text/xml");
                        client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                        client.println();
                        SetLEDs();
                        // send XML file containing input states
                        XML_response(client);
                    }
                    else {  // web page request
                        // send rest of HTTP header
                        client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                        client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                        client.println();
                        // send web page
                        webFile = SD.open("index.htm");        // open web page file
                        if (webFile) {
                            while(webFile.available()) {
                                client.write(webFile.read()); // send web page to client
                            }
                            webFile.close();
                        }
                    }
                    // display received HTTP request on serial port
                    Serial.print(HTTP_req);
                    // reset buffer index and all buffer elements to 0
                    req_index = 0;
                    StrClear(HTTP_req, REQ_BUF_SZ);
                    break;
                }
                // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
                if (c == '\n') {
                    // last character on line of received text
                    // starting new line with next character read
                    currentLineIsBlank = true;
                } 
                else if (c != '\r') {
                    // a text character was received from client
                    currentLineIsBlank = false;
                }
            } // end if (client.available())
        } // end while (client.connected())
        delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
        client.stop(); // close the connection
    } // end if (client)
}

// checks if received HTTP request is switching on/off LEDs
// also saves the state of the LEDs
void SetLEDs(void)
{

    // LED 3 (pin 8)
    if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED1=1")) {
        LED_state[0] = 1;  // save LED state
        actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'A',true);
        Serial.print("button 1 on ");
    }
    else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED1=0")) {
        LED_state[0] = 0;  // save LED state
        actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'A',false);
        Serial.print("button 1 off");
    }
    // LED 4 (pin 9)
    if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED2=1")) {
        LED_state[1] = 1;  // save LED state
        actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'B',true);
    }
    else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED2=0")) {
        LED_state[1] = 0;  // save LED state
        actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'B',false);
    }
     if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED3=1")) {
        LED_state[2] = 1;  // save LED state
        actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'C',true);
    }
    else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED3=0")) {
        LED_state[2] = 0;  // save LED state
        actionTransmitter.sendSignal(1,'C',false);
    }
}

// send the XML file with analog values, switch status
//  and LED status
void XML_response(EthernetClient cl)
{
    int analog_val;            // stores value read from analog inputs
    int count;                 // used by 'for' loops


    cl.print("<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>");
    cl.print("<inputs>");


    // button LED states
    // LED3
    cl.print("<LED>");
    if (LED_state[0]) {
        cl.print("on");

    }
    else {
        cl.print("off");

    }
    cl.println("</LED>");
    // LED4
    cl.print("<LED>");
    if (LED_state[1]) {
        cl.print("on");
    }
    else {
        cl.print("off");
    }
    cl.println("</LED>");

    // new led
    cl.print("<LED>");
    if (LED_state[2]) {
        cl.print("on");

    }
    else {
        cl.print("off");

    }
    cl.println("</LED>");

    cl.print("</inputs>");
}


// sets every element of str to 0 (clears array)
void StrClear(char *str, char length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        str[i] = 0;
    }
}

// searches for the string sfind in the string str
// returns 1 if string found
// returns 0 if string not found
char StrContains(char *str, char *sfind)
{
    char found = 0;
    char index = 0;
    char len;

    len = strlen(str);

    if (strlen(sfind) > len) {
        return 0;
    }
    while (index < len) {
        if (str[index] == sfind[found]) {
            found++;
            if (strlen(sfind) == found) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            found = 0;
        }
        index++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description... There is a possibility you are running out of memory. Of course, this is only a possibility. Try using the FreeMemory library to monitor memory utilization. If the amount of memory declines each time you send a command, then you have your answer.

Note that Arduino sketches just fail when they use up the last of their memory (typically). The stack overlays some data area and the sketch goes crazy in some way.

Of course, you will need to run your sketch with the Serial Monitor to take a look at the FreeMemory output. Putting in a few Serial.print statement might also help determine exactly where your sketch is hanging

Great idea by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem when using an Arduino to remotely control a Solenoid. What I found was that the problem stems from receiving an HTML request while the Arduino was still transmitting its web page to the client.

See if the code still hangs if you give it several seconds in between requests; if so, try to slim down your transmitted web page, or make sure no requests are taken until transmission of the server's reply is complete.

Answer (score 0):

i have had similar issues, i have a web server that needed a reboot every 24 hours.  This allowed it to work solidly for over a year. Recently i have been trying to get rid of the reboot solution, and may have found a better solution.  I also looked at the usual s, disable sd card, free memory, dchp memory leak, router ip lease time and a bunch of others.  All of these turned out to be red herrings and did not improve the stability. Finally i tried including the ethernet.begin and server.begin in the main loop and it has now worked for over a week without reboot. I suggest firing these lines every hour or day rather than continuously.  Might be an issue when millis overflows, cant comment as thats around 40 days away at the moment.